# Validate whether a date ia avalid date

Tags: javascript, validation, date, datetime

I'm trying to validate across platforms and browsers, whether a date is a valid date or not.

I tried the following and it worked consistently accross browsers (IE5+, Firefox, Chrome):

`isNaN(new Date())`
`--> false`

`isNaN(new Date(0))`
`--> false`

`isNaN(new Date("Fri May 20 2016 12:58:52 GMT+0530"))`
`--> false`

`isNaN(new Date("asd"))`
`--> true`

The first 3 are valid dates and whereever the output is false it means the date is valid.

Please confirm whether this is right.

PS: This question is not about date formats. This question is about identifying whether a date is valid Javascript `Date` object or not. For example, in the try-outs above `new Date("asd")` is obviously not a date.

Comment: I don't understand down votes without comments, or even a single close vote.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

> ```
> isNaN(new Date())
> --> false
> ```

Here, *new Date()* creates a valid new date. *isNaN* then calls *ToNumber* on the newly created *Date*, which will return its time value, which isn't NaN so the return value is *false*.

> ```
> isNaN(new Date(0))
> --> false
> ```

This create a valid date with a time value of 0 (equivalent to 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), which isn't NaN so returns false.

> ```
> isNaN(new Date("Fri May 20 2016 12:58:52 GMT+0530"))
> --> false
> ```

This may or may not create a valid Date object since that depends on the implementation dependent behaviour of the parser to create a valid date (or not). So whether it returns true or false is problematic.

> ```
> isNaN(new Date("asd"))
> --> true
> ```

As above, getting the expected result depends on an implementation dependent parser creating an invalid date (though it is highly likely that a parser will create an invalid date).

Beyound testing, you can always read the specification. It states that an invalid Date object has a time value of NaN. So a reliable way to determine if it's a valid date or not is to either check the time value or the value returned by any of the *get* methods (*getYear*, *getMonth*, etc.).

Any of the following will do:

```js
var d0 = new Date(NaN)  // Create an invalid date.
var d1 = new Date(2016) // Create a valid date

// Tests for invalid date
// Let isNaN coerce the date to Number
console.log(isNaN(d0) + ' : ' + isNaN(d1))
// Test the time value explicitly
console.log(isNaN(d0.getTime()) + ' : ' + isNaN(d1.getTime()));
// Use unary + to coerce the Date to Number
console.log(isNaN(+d0) + ' : ' + isNaN(+d1));
// Use a get method
console.log(isNaN(d0.getDate()) + ' : ' + isNaN(d1.getDate()));

// Not using isNaN - test the value returned by *toString*
console.log((d0.toString() == 'Invalid Date') + ' : ' + (d1.toString() == 'Invalid Date'));
```

The last method isn't that reliable since *Date.prototype.toString* can be overwritten and return some other value (not a good idea or likely, but possible).

Answer (score -2):

Javascript is good way to go for cross-browser date validation. If you can get your dates in the normal dd/mm/yyyy format, here is a good regex validation example to check that a date string is valid: -

```
    var theDate = '31/12/2016'
    var reg = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d/;
    return theDate.match(reg);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy` isn't a "normal" format since it depends on your locale. `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` (*ISO 8601*) is much more standard.

Comment: @Steveo, This question is not about date formats. This question is about identifying whether a date is valid Javascript `Date` object or not.

Comment: @C.Champagne—it isn't really about "locale", but user preferences. An American likely wants to see mm/dd/yyyy regardless of where they are. ISO 8601 is "much more standard" because it **is** a standard. ;-)

Comment: @RobG yes  ISO-8601 **is** a standard. Maybe I should have written something like "is a standard and therefore more universal"... I don't know.. Sorry for using the *locale* word  (I was probably influenced by my java background) but I was talking about the parametrisation, not the location. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)

Comment: @C.Champagne—using "locale" instead of "preference" really isn't your fault, the term has been misused by the computer industry for some time. "Culture" was used used for a time, but now "locale" seems to be in vogue. The *toLocaleString* method should be called *toFormattedString*, IMO of course. ;-)